# How to use identical function to compare list of matrices by the row

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of two matrices, `x` and `y`.

```
 x <- c(3,4,5,5,
3,4,5,6,
5,6,2,1)

x <- matrix(x,3,4)

y <- c(3,4,5,5,
3,4,5,6,
5,5,2,1)

y <- matrix(y,3,4)

d <- list(x, y)

> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    5    5    6
[2,]    4    3    6    2
[3,]    5    4    5    1

> y
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    5    5    5
[2,]    4    3    6    2
[3,]    5    4    5    1
```

I would like to compare each row of these two matrices using the `identical` function. Here, the two matrices are the same unless for the last element of the first row.

How could I compare these two matrices, row by row? Any help, please?

My tried is:

```
res <- round(apply(array(unlist(d), c(4, 4, 4)), c(1,2), identical),2)
```

(from there "[I tried the code used here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351013/standard-deviation-over-a-list-of-matrices-in-r))

But I have got an error:

*Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : argument "y" is missing, with no default*

**Please note that the element of the list is arbitrary. That is, sometimes, I have only 2 matrices, however, another time may I have 6 matrices**

**The expected output should be like this**

```
output:
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
[2,]    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
[3,]    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
```

Comment: You want row by row or element by element? If you want to check if they are identical, whats the point doing it row by row? Also, can you have more than two matrices in a list?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm guessing they actually want to see where it's different.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you so much for your comment. My original funciton is very difficult. I store the result of a specific output of a model as a matrix. Hence, I really need to compare it pair-by pair. Sometimes the dimension of my matrix is `100`.

Comment: So how do you want to compare 3 or 4 matrices? e.g., how would your desired output look like?

Comment: Hence, If I compare them row-by-row (element by element) it will become more easy for me.

Comment: If you want to compare all of your matrices, one way could be `combn(seq_along(d), 2, function(x) d[x][[1]]- d[x][[2]])`

Comment: You might be looking to calculate the mode of each matrix position and compare all to that as well - there is still not enough context.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Nice, but leads to an ambiguous output, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** This defines `Identical` to be a function which returns TRUE if all its arguments are identical.  It does this by computing the `sd` of its arguments and comparing that to zero.  The second line of code applies this to the corresponding elements of the matrices.

```
Identical <- function(...) sd(c(...)) == 0
array(do.call("mapply", c(Identical, d)), dim(d[[1]]))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

A few alternate ways to define Identical.  These have the advantage that they work with non-numeric matrices as well.  The second one uses `identical` as requested.

```
Identical <- function(...) all(c(...)[-1] == ..1)

Identical <- function(...) all(sapply(c(...)[-1], identical, ..1))
```

**2)** This alternate method is only one line of code and uses the whole object approach with no explicit use of dimensions or indexes.  It unlists `d` and applies `sd` over corresponding elements of that using `tapply`.  Finally it compares that to zero.

```
tapply(unlist(d), list(sapply(d, row), sapply(d, col)), sd) == 0
```

**2a)** A variation is to define the comparison as a separate function:

```
Same <- function(x) sd(x) == 0
tapply(unlist(d), list(sapply(d, row), sapply(d, col)), Same)
```

That makes it easier to define alternatives by redefining `Same` such as the following where the second definition uses `identical`.

```
Same <- function(x) all(x[-1] == x[1])

Same <- function(x) all(sapply(x[-1], identical, x[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple solution**

The example in the OP doesn't require `identical`, it can be solved this way :

Compare all matrices to the first one and `Reduce` with `&` :

```
Reduce(`&`, lapply(d[-1], `==`, d[[1]]))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
# [1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
# [2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

**Using `identical`**

However, `identical` and `==` behave differently in general, using identical we can do :

```
matrix(
  Reduce(`&`, lapply(d[-1], function(x) mapply(identical, x, d[[1]]))),
  nrow(d[[1]]))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
# [1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
# [2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

**How do they differ ?** (examples)

```
f1 <- function(d) Reduce(`&`, lapply(d[-1], `==`, d[[1]]))
f2 <- function(d) matrix(Reduce(`&`, lapply(d[-1], function(x) mapply(identical, x, d[[1]]))),nrow(d[[1]]))
```

`NA == NA` is `NA` while `identical(NA,NA)` is `TRUE`, so the following give a different result for `f1` and `f2`:

```
x_na <- x
x_na[3,1] <- NA
d_na <- list(x_na, y)

f1(d_na)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
# [1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
# [2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
# [3,]   NA TRUE TRUE  TRUE

f2(d_na)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
# [1,]  TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

`==` fails on lists while `identical` doesn't, so in the following `f1` will crash :

```
x_list <- apply(x,c(1,2),list) # a matrix of list, similar to op's input but filled with length one lists
y_list <- apply(y,c(1,2),list)
z_list <- x_list            # we build a 3rd item
z_list[3,1] <- list("foo")  # # which differs from x2 on [3,1]
d_list <- list(x_list, y_list, z_list)

f1(d_list)
# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : comparison of these types is not implemented

f2(d_list)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
# [1,]  TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat the list as an array.
This method will tell you where and how large the differences are, also when the list contains more than two matrices.

```
x <- matrix(c(3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 2, 1), 3, 4)
y <- matrix(c(3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 2, 1), 3, 4)
z <- matrix(c(3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 6, 5, 5, 2, 1), 3, 4)
d <- list(x, y, z)

library(abind)

d.arr <- do.call(abind, c(d, list(along=3)))
aperm(apply(d.arr, 1:2, diff), c(2, 3, 1))
# , , 1

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0   -1
# [2,]    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0

# , , 2

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0   -1    0    0
```

For a simple boolean `identical` collapsed into a matrix:

```
apply(d.arr, 1:2, function(x) all(diff(x) == 0))
#      [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]
# [1,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE
# [2,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] TRUE FALSE TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are only doing two it is better to just use the difference of the two.

```
x <-  matrix(c(3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 2, 1), 3, 4)
y <-  matrix(c(3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 2, 1), 3, 4)

which(rowSums(x - y) != 0)
```

if you read `?identical` you will see that it only does two.

---

```
x <- matrix(c(3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 2, 1), 3, 4)
y <- matrix(c(3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 2, 1), 3, 4)
z <- matrix(c(3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 6, 5, 5, 2, 1), 3, 4)

d <- list(x, y, z)
```

With an arbitrary number of matrices we do not know where the baselines are,
if we have more than three we can use the mode potentially.

```
library(modeest)

matrix_diff_locations <- function(l) {

  dimensions <- sapply(l, dim)
  dimensions <- apply(dimensions, 1, unique)

  stopifnot(length(dimensions) <= 2)

  baseline <- apply(matrix(unlist(l), ncol = length(l)), 1, mfv)
  baseline <- matrix(baseline, nrow = dimensions[1], ncol = dimensions[2])

  lapply(l, function(x) x - baseline)

}
matrix_diff_locations(d)

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0   -1    0    0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I do it for arbitrary number of element of the list.

Comment: @Maryam you wont be able to tell which one is "correct" but which one is less common? `identical` does not handle more than single pair.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just knew that now. Thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

To compare any number of matrices, you could look at the variances.

```
apply(array(unlist(d), c(3, 4, length(d))), c(1, 2), 
      function(x) ifelse(var(x) == 0, TRUE, FALSE))
```

or as @zacdav in comments suggests just

```
apply(array(unlist(d), c(3, 4, length(d))), c(1, 2), 
      function(x) var(x) == 0)
```

*Test:*

```
> apply(array(unlist(d), c(3, 4, length(d))), c(1, 2), 
+       function(x) var(x) == 0)
      [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

***Additional data***

```
z <- matrix(c(3,4,9,2,
       3,4,5,6,
       5,5,2,1), 3, 4)
d <- list(x, y, z)
```

Comment: this is much less efficient than straight up subtraction.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I do not know how to answer my question myself. Hence,  I asked. My try is what I think it is ok. However, I provide that It does not work. In addition, I mentioned that the number of my matrices is arbitrary.

Comment: @Maryam So why did you accept an answer that doesn't meet your requirements

Comment: to be honest I don't think either answer matches her requirements.

Comment: Yes, You are correct. I should not accept it because it used `rowSums(x-y)` which only worked for two. I accept it because now my list has only two matrices.  Thank you so much for your comment.

Comment: @jaySf `ifelse(var(x) == 0, TRUE, FALSE)` could just be `var(x) == 0` ?

Comment: @zacdav sure, nice, I've added this to my answer!